# What is the requirement for new ships/derelicts to arrive?

Tags: spacebase-df-9

One can double wall the base, to prevent derelicts and new ships appearing.

In my testing, "opening" up a small section of wall is not enough to make neither new ships or derelicts to show up.

Does anyone know in more detail what makes the difference?

Ideally it would be nice to be build a construction "just at the edge", being able to switch back and forth by adding/removing a single piece of wall.

Comment: I believe it has more to do with if the double wall is recognized as external wall of your base. I can't confirm it in the upcoming days, but I suggest you to test it. Make connection 1 wall or 1 room connection to the external wall. I think then you will get these events again. Supposed derelict blueprint I think would overlap your built base tiles, and so prove to be invalid, and so will not going to take place (after a code side validity check).

Comment: @Sonic Wow, does your comment mean people actually play still? I dropped the game when they "cancelled" it years ago. I wouldn't have expected to see any activity on a related question. :)

Comment: I was in the mid of playing, when the cancelling happened. I have a big heart for colony building, and survival designing, so I kept playing till I felt challenges in there. Can't remember, when did I play last time, but is is already a while :) Nevertheless, I started to go through all tags in this section, and respond, where I have relevant info. That's how I found your question :)

Comment: @Sonic I'm going completely off-topic here, but since you're a fan of the genre, I have to ask what other games you've picked up and liked since? I'd love to try some alternatives. :) (Rimworld being my personal favorite)

Comment: Well, to respect the StackExchange rules, lets fire up a chat or drive it to another channel - you can reach me at "kasza [dot] z [at] gmail [dot] com". Still to do a respond in short, in the genre I liked Banished, Craft The World, RimWorld (Alpha13). I'm waiting for Maia, and avoiding Farlight Explorers (and it's clones), and Planetbase. For alternatives it can be several, it worths to describe what direction you like.